# Careers has incorrect grammar in tooltip on My Profile Page

Tags: feature-request, jobs, cv, grammar

On the page http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit, when one is adding experience, with the `IsCurrent` checkbox ticked and the `<input id="tags">` with focus, the `class="field-help" for="Tags"` tooltip contains the text:

`A list of up to 10 core technologies you used on this job.`

I know it is a minor change, and very picky, but think it is worth mentioning that given the technologies listed are for the current position, the tooltip should probably say something like:

`A list of up to 10 core technologies you have used to date on this job.`

Comment: You said it right, I can't upvote.. so leaving a comment.

Comment: @gnat - Thanks. What a time to make a mistake! :)